# VS Code Jupyter Notebook looks different from release notes

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm new VS Code and Jupyter Notebooks. In the recent release notes, I noticed the Notebook looks different than mine but I couldn't figure out how to get it - hence I'm not able to use the new features. These features are not listed under 'Preview' features either. Both my VS Code (Stable) and Jupyter extension are the latest.

**Release notes with screenshots**

- April - https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56#_notebooks
- March - https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_55#_notebooks

**How mine looks like**
[image: My VS Code cell]

Thanks!

Comment: Please name just one "new feature" that you can't access.

Comment: Hi, generally the whole notebook is different. I need to use VS Code Insiders as @joyceerhl pointed out below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshots are of the preview native notebooks interface, which is currently only available in [VS Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders).

Please note that new Jupyter extension users in VS Code Insiders must currently add the following setting to their settings.json for the extension to work, due to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5804:

```
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter-notebook",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining, and pointing me to the latest issue too! I've got it working now.

Comment: Btw, do you also know when the native notebook will go into stable release?

Comment: We're working on bringing it to stable ASAP (I'm a dev on the extension), but there's currently no specific date I can offer.